In how many ways can the integers $1,2, \dots ,n$ be arranged so that there is only one integer that is immediately followed by a smaller integer?
I attempted this using an recursive idea. I noticed that as long as $1$ does not appear on the first position and it appears on the $k$-th position, then there are exactly $n$ choose $k$ number of arrangements possible. However, are there any more methods that are much more straightforward?

Split the set $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ into two subsets $A$ and $B$. Now list the elements of $A$ in increasing order, followed by the elements of $B$ in increasing order. What you get is an arrangement that satisfies your criterion, provided that the largest element of $A$ is greater than the smallest element of $B$. Moreover, all valid arrangements can be obtained in this way.
So you want the number of ways of splitting into two subsets (which is $2^n$) minus the number of ways of splitting into two subsets where every element of $A$ is less than every element of $B$ (which is $n+1$).

Makes perfect sense. Thank you!

You want to split it up into 2 non-empty subsets right? IE $ A = [n]$ doesn't work.

@CalvinLin: I think I got it right: the two splits that result in an empty subset are subtracted from the total (hence $n+1$).

As in, paragraph 1 as it stands is incorrect, because you also need the condition that $A, B$ are non-empty. Your proof requires a "largest element of A" and "smallest element of B", which isn't guaranteed. $\quad$    I agree that the "not accounting for the previous error" in paragraph 2 fixes it.

@CalvinLin: Oh yes, you are right. So instead of $2^n-(n+1)$, we get $(2^n-2)-(n-1)$. Which fortunately gives the same answer!
